# Post request data is not being inserted into mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I've made below post request, which seem to work fine. when i look in developer tools under network everything seem to work and i can see that each parameter is being posted. however when the `insert.php` is executed nothing is added to the database and i'm not receiving any error message. I'm trying to save the image into a Blob in mysql.

**post request**

```
var description = $('#description').val();
var title = $('#title').val();

var fileInput = $("#image")[0];
var file = fileInput.files[0];
var dataResult = new FormData();
dataResult.append('image', file);
dataResult.append('desc', description);
dataResult.append('title', title);
dataResult.append('longitude', currentMarker.lng());
dataResult.append('latitude', currentMarker.lat());

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'insert.php',
  data: dataResult,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
        success: function (answer) {

        }
    })
```

**insert.php**

```
include('config.php');

if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['body']) && isset($_POST['longitude']) && isset($_POST['latitude'])){
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $body = $_POST['body'];
  $longitude = (float)$_POST['longitude'];
  $latitude = (float)$_POST['latitude'];
  $file = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['name']);


  $strSQL = $db->query("INSERT INTO camps (title, body, longitude, latitude, image) VALUES ('$title',  '$body', '$longitude','$latitude', '$file')");


}
```

**Dump**

```
array(4) {
  ["desc"]=>
  string(6) "teeest"
  ["title"]=>
  string(11) "test"
  ["longitude"]=>
  string(18) "-74.17870044708252"
  ["latitude"]=>
  string(17) "40.73480350827126"
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can put your `$db->query` into a try catch block and catch the Exception, if there is one. Did you already check the webservers error log and or the mysql error log? What is the raw version of the query?

Comment: `var_dump` `$_POST` to check what you received. You may use Postman -rest client for ajax request if you are on Chrome.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to your `insert.php` at the begining after php starting tag and try again and let us know if you get any error..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

1. There is no output of the script, nor any error handling and when you get the output back in the `answer` variable, you don't do anything with it. You should at least dump that to the console to see what is happening.
2. You will never enter your `if` block as there is no element with a key of `body`
3. The path to your file is not `$_FILES['image']['name']` but `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']`.
4. You have an sql injection problem. You should use a prepared statement with bound variables instead of injecting your variables directly in the query.

There may be more but when you add error handling and use the output of the script, you will at least be able to see what is wrong exactly.

Apart from that I would recommend that you store the file as a file in the file-system and just add the path to the database.

Comment: so i need to var_dump `$strSQL`?

Comment: @PeterPik Not only that, now you don't enter the `if` condition so an `else` with a dump of `$_POST` would also be helpful.

Comment: so i've added the dump response with `var_dump($_POST);`. does this mean that the image hasnt been sent as a post request or would i need   var_dump($_FILES); for this?